# problem running scons

Tags: python, scons

I am trying to get started with [scons](http://www.scons.org/). I have Python 3.0.1 and downloaded Scons 1.2.0; when I try to run scons I get the following error. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
C:\tmp\scons>c:\appl\python\3.0.1\Scripts\scons
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\appl\python\3.0.1\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.2.0\SCons\__init__.py", l
ine 43, in <module>
    import SCons.compat
  File "c:\appl\python\3.0.1\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.2.0\SCons\compat\__init__
.py", line 208
    raise Error, "Cannot move a directory '%s' into itself '%s'." % (src, dst)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's Python 2 syntax. I assume scons doesn't run on Python 3. You need to run it using Python 2.

Comment: ah, i'll try that, then. Very odd; the documentation http://www.scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions says "SCons is written to work with Python version 1.5.2 or any later version. Extensive tests are used to ensure that SCons works on all supported versions."

Comment: btw is it better to put the python/Scripts directory in my path, or copy the scons.bat file into my c:\bin directory (which is in my path)?

Comment: That FAQ was last changed the day before 3.0 was released. ;) For your other question, why don't you post it as a question?

Comment: Python 3 has extensive syntax changes and will not be backwards compatible.